# RxJs - forkJoin with empty array

Tags: rxjs

I'm currently using `forkJoin` to wait for an array of `Observable`(s) to finish before `pipe`(ing) and `tap`(ping).

I noticed if the array is empty nothing is emitted and I cannot even `tap`. How do I solve this kind of problem? Should I just check if the array is empty?

```
myFirstFunction(...) {
   const observables = ...
   return forkJoin(observables)
}

mySecondFunction(...) {
   return myFirstFunction().pipe(tap(() => ...))
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

That's because `forkJoin` requires all source Observables to emit at least one item and when there are no source Observables there's nothing to emit. However, `forkJoin` will still send the `complete` notification so you can use for example `defaultIfEmpty` operator to make sure it always emits at least one `next`.

```
forkJoin(observables).pipe(
  defaultIfEmpty(null),
).subscribe(...);
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kkd1qa?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks Martin. Is the "will still send the complete notification" related only to the `forkJoin` operator or is it more general?

Comment: That's related to `forkJoin`'s internal functionality.

Comment: I asked because I was looking at this page https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html and found nothing mentioning this.
Oh btw, had to use `defaultIfEmpty([])`

Comment: This is as edge case so I'm not surprised it's not mentioned there. I don't think this behavior is mentioned not even in the official documentation. You can see that it really works here https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kkd1qa?file=index.ts

Answer (score 9):

Additionally to martin's answer.

I had 2 observables returning arrays and if one of them gives me an empty array, it did not wait for the other observable to finish and completed instantly. You can handle such cases as follows using `defaultIfEmpty`.

```
const response1: Observable<any[]> = this.service.getResponse(params1).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]));
const response2: Observable<any[]> = this.service.getResponse(params2).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]));

Observable.forkJoin(response1, response2).subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response);
}, () => {
  console.log('handle error here');
}, () => {
  console.log('completed');
});
```