# Rxjs Observable Array of Objects add key/pair

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have angular App with State management which is work in where i load data from database in observable like

let first give you interface

```
interface service {
  id: number,
  name:string,
  category_id: number,
}

interface category{
  id:number,
  name:string,
}
```

As you can see there is relation between service and category which link by id which is number.

Let give you what is observable look like

```
services : Observable<Service[]>

categories : Observable<Category[]>
```

How can i merge Category name into Services into something differnt like this:

```
interface ServiceWithCategory{
  id: number,
  name:string,
  category_id: number,
  category:string,
}
```

I try to to some async pipe in angular but it don't update if category updated

```
const serviceswithcategory = services.pipe(
      map(i => i.map((service) => {
        return {
          ...service,
          Category: `${this.async.transform(categories.pipe(map((i) => { 
           return i.find((a: Category) => a.id == service.category_id) }))?.name}
           }`
        }
      })));
```

Now serviceswithcategory don't do anything when category get udpated. It is not reactive to category.

Comment: While the answer is very nice, but if you code also the backend, consider retrieving the data in the structure you want.

Comment: it totally front end using ngxs

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code you're after:

```
forkJoin({ services: services$, categories: categories$ })
  .pipe(
    map(({ services, categories }) => {
      const categoriesById = categories.reduce((acc, category) => {
        acc[category.id] = category;
        return acc;
      }, {});

      return services.map((service) => ({
        id: service.id,
        name: service.name,
        category: categoriesById[service.category_id],
      }));
    })
  )
```

- `forkJoin` let us get the result of the 2 observables
- Using a `reduce`, we transform the categories into a dictionary of categories to be able to access them by ID instead of having a loop in a loop (to find a category for each service) which wouldn't be efficient
- We then map onto the services and get the corresponding category

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Service 1",
        "category": {
            "id": 100,
            "name": "Category 100"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Service 2",
        "category": {
            "id": 200,
            "name": "Category 200"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Service 3",
        "category": {
            "id": 100,
            "name": "Category 100"
        }
    }
]
```

Here's a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xp5gej?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) (look at the console for the output).

Comment: sorry it don't work in angular Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

Comment: it return null on angular sharing angular live example soon

Comment: strange it work there

Comment: You probably just need to cast the accumulator of the reduce defined as `{}` and instead put `{} as Record<number, TheOtherTypeThatHasBothNameAndCategory>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53477784/rxjs-forkjoin-with-empty-array it relates to this issue.

Comment: removing marked solution can work when use of but if you use some kind of services it don't work it seem work fast and not give any time observable to load.

Comment: One can only answer what you asked for. I replied with a working live demo. Next time if you want a demo from a service, ask a question mentioning that and give some example code. If you change your mind 13 days later, just create a new question.

Comment: So sorry because your example is definitely work but within the limit. I see your option work and assume it will work on project also and don't test in live code.

Comment: also mergeMap if you wait a little i provide code to you and make this answer 100% useful. like  this.service_plans.allState().pipe(
    mergeMap(service_plans => {
      return this.services.allState().pipe(
        map(services => {
          return service_plans.map((service_plan) => ({
            ...service_plan,
            Service: services.find(i => i.id == service_plan.service_id)?.name
          }))
        })
      )
    })
  )

Comment: Please don't take offense it answer have to useful to future also.